# Convertir un string a una lista

Tags: python, lista

¿Cómo podría convertir el string que esta en la variable texto en una lista de nuevo?

```
lista=[11, 'Alejandro', 'nota: 4.9',  'asistencia 1/1/2021: sí',  'asistencia 2/1/2021: no']
texto=str(lista) 

#convertir el contenido de la variable texto a una lista de nuevo.
```

Answer (score 1):

si es como lo interpreto , sólo necesítas cambiar el nombre del método, espero te sírva.

```
lista = [11 , 'alejandro' , 'nota: 4.9' , 'asistencia 1/1/2021: sí ' , 'asistencia 2/1/2021: no ']

texto = str (lista)
print (texto)
print()
print (type (texto)) # línea para que veas el método
print()

texto = list (lista)
print (texto)
print()
print (type (texto)) # línea para que veas el nuevo método asignado
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Comment: un placer , suerte.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir lo que quieres no es algo tan evidente, pero desde luego que es posible. Podemos valernos del módulo `json` para conseguir esto, dado tu caso particular.

La idea es pasar la string que tienes (`texto`), como argumento a `json.loads()`. Este método se encarga de convertir texto en formato JSON a objetos de Python.

Sin embargo, para que `texto` pueda ser analizado válidamente como JSON, es necesario cumplir con el hecho de que los elementos que sean cadenas de caracteres (strings) deben ser representados con comillas (`"`) en lugar de con apóstrofes (`'`). Esto lo podemos lograr a través del método `replace()` de la clase `str`.

El código quedaría como se muestra a continuación:

```
import json


lista = [11, 'Alejandro', 'nota: 4.9',  'asistencia 1/1/2021: sí',  'asistencia 2/1/2021: no']
texto = str(lista)

lista_de_nuevo = json.loads(texto.replace("'", '"'))
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

veamos:
texto es una representación de la lista como tal en cadena, o sea que comenzará con [ y por lo tanto terminará en ] que ambos símbolos son los delimitadores de lista, como quieres volver a tener la lista, aunque ésta como tal sigue intacta, sería usar el método de cadenas split() que convierte cadenas en listas recibiendo como parámetro el separador que por defecto es el carácter de espacio, en este caso hay que separar pasando como separador el carácter coma ",":

```
nueva=texto[1:-1].split(",")
```

lo que si hago un slice de la cadena del primer y último carácter para que no sean incluidos en la conversión